# Spring <prop> tag

Tags: spring

I have

```
   <bean id="dao" class="......"> 
      <property name="foo">
         <props>
           <prop key="me">Homer</prop>
         <props>
       <property>
   </bean>
```

I want to use my current properties file, name-value pair, to change "Homer"
I cannot figure it out...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer bean.  Example here:

http://static.springframework.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html#beans-factory-placeholderconfigurer